# PictureCaptureCallback or CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

Hello I have a CameraCaptureSession object and I dont know which Capture Callback to pass to its setRepeatingRequest method. I know PictureCaptureCallback extends CameraCaptureSession but which one should I use or is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `CaptureCallback` is an abstract class, you have to provide an implementation of that class defining what to do when something happens (for example "on ready").

Here is an example:

```
PictureCaptureCallback mCaptureCallback = new PictureCaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPrecaptureRequired() {
            doSomething();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReady() {
            capturePicture();
        }
};
```

And then you pass that implementation to the method:

```
mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, null);
```

These callback methods are then called by the `CameraCaptureSession` in case of the corresponding event.